# Block specific IP from accessing gateway

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, iptables, routing

Suppose you are on linux internet gateway/router. What would you do to block a client with specific IP using bash script. I prefer something like `./block_client.sh 192.168.1.123` to block and `./unblock_client.sh 192.168.1.123`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ cat block_client.sh
#!/bin/bash
iptables -I INPUT -s 192.168.1.123 -j DROP
$ cat unblock_client.sh
#!/bin/bash
iptables -D INPUT -s 192.168.1.123 -j DROP
```

Comment: The IP block will not survive a reboot unless they are saved on update and restored on boot. look up `iptables-save` and `iptables-restore`. On Redhat like systems, you can get away with a simple "`/etc/init.d/iptables save`".

Answer (score 1):

You might want to deploy something like [apf](http://www.rfxn.com/projects/advanced-policy-firewall/) which you'll be able to execute `apf -d 192.168.1.123` and `apf -u 192.168.1.123` to block and unblock respectively. In addition APF keeps it's blocks list local and will insert them into the iptables on each reboot.